# Excel VBA code to Find and Replace not working properly

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find

I wrote a Find and Replace Sub in VBA Macros to find specific strings and replace them with some numbers. There are 30 blocks of code but the block 10 and block 15 does not work. And example of ones that work is this below:

```
'1. Lesson Plan/Session notes available and provides up-to-date information relevant to the session being taught.

Range("AD2:AD167").Replace What:="Lesson plan is incomplete or unavailable or lesson plan is available but does not follow the acceptable format and does not cover the relevant indicator(s).", Replacement:="1"
Range("AD2:AD167").Replace What:="Lesson plan is available and complete, follows the acceptable format, provides adequate information but does not cover the relevant indicator(s).", Replacement:="2"
Range("AD2:AD167").Replace What:="complete, follows the acceptable format, provides adequate information but only partially covers the relevant /indicator(s).", Replacement:="3"
Range("AD2:AD167").Replace What:="Lesson plan is available and complete, follows the acceptable format, provides adequate information and covers all the relevant indicator(s).", Replacement:="4"
```

Obvisously they are all enclosed in the Sub amd End Sub.

The following are the blocks that are causing problems:

```
'10. Teacher’s feedback: Clarifies learners’ misconceptions, encourages discussion among them without any discrimination 'and helps identify their successes.

Range("AX2:AX167").Replace What:="Teacher does not keep learners occupied with activities.", Replacement:="1"
Range("AX2:AX167").Replace What:="Teacher guides learners after assigning activities to learners and gives regular prompts to keep them concentrated.", Replacement:="2"
Range("AX2:AX167").Replace What:="Teacher guides learners after assigning activities to learners and gives regular prompts to keep them concentrated and encourages peer feedback.", Replacement:="3"
Range("AX2:AX167").Replace What:="Teacher guides learners after assigning activities to learners and gives regular prompts to keep them concentrated, encourages peer feedback and indicates what is expected of them.", Replacement:="4"
```

For the block 10 above: It doesnt state any issues, it just doesnt replace anything and then moves on to block 11 which works fine.

The code run ends at block 15 below and throws up and error message: Runtime Error 13: Type Mismatch

```
'15. Rotations:   Are being carried out for facilitated activities at the learning centres.

Range("BH2:BH167").Replace What:="Indoor and outdoor learning centres are available for few learners to play and learn alone or together. Occasionally the teacher provides facilitation.", Replacement:="1"
Range("BH2:BH167").Replace What:="Indoor and outdoor learning centres are available for majority of learners to play and learn alone or together to explore specific activities independently while the teacher provides small-group facilitation. Regular prompts are given to learners to tidy up and move to another activity.", Replacement:="2"
Range("BH2:BH167").Replace What:="Indoor and outdoor learning centres are available for most learners to play and learn alone or together to explore specific activities independently while the teacher provides small-group facilitation. Regular prompts are given to learners to tidy up and move to another activity.", Replacement:="3"
Range("BH2:BH167").Replace What:="Indoor and outdoor learning centres are available for all learners to play and learn alone or together to explore specific activities independently while the teacher provides small-group facilitation.  Regular prompts are given to learners to tidy up and move to another activity", Replacement:="4"
```

I have read through all the lines and it seems perfect. i dont understand why those 2 particular blocks do not work. Someone please help me fix it

Comment: It'd be best to also use the `LookAt` parameter.

Comment: Excel remembers the settings from your last search, so to be sure you are using the right settings, make sure you include the settings in your code.

Comment: Try something shorter to check that it isn't some whitespace error affecting matches in the block that doesn't work. eg Replace What:="Teacher guides learners", Replacement "TGL" and see it that works OK.

Comment: Also, note that the *Find* method's `MatchCase` argument is by default set to `False` which is not the case with the *Replace* method. Let us know what fixed your issue (`LookAt` or `MatchCase`)>

Comment: Can someone show me how to use either the MatchCase or LookAt by an example?

Comment: `... , Replacement:="1", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False`, The other options are `xlWhole` and `True` respectively. Study the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace).